# Jquery on for future elements not working?

Tags: jquery, future

I have a click function...

```
$('.rx').children().on('click',function(){alert('got here');});
```

My divs (50 of these div sets on the page)...

```
<div class="rx"><div id="'.$data_string.'" class="'.$button_image_class.'"><a  href="#" ></a></div></div>
```

(each  is a css sprite image button, which sends the $data_string in the id to a function "process_me".  I've replaced the call to process_me with an alert('got here'); for this question.  FYI the $button_image_class is variable, as a particular image is loaded depending on the member's account)

It all works beautifully, until I use pagination to load in more of the above divs (another 50, exactly the same bar $data_string, which is different in all the divs anyway).

The sprite image button links in the first 50 divs work how they should - clicking them prompts 'got here'.  However, the  links in the newly loaded div sets don't work.

I first guessed it's because the DOM isn't picking up the new elements, but  .on('click',function()... is supposed to pick up future elements.  So now I'm thinking it's something in

```
$('.rx').children().on('click',function(){alert('got here');});
```

that I've done wrong.

Anything sticking out there?

Comment: `$('.rx').on('click','*',function(){alert('got here');});`

Comment: where `*` is the future selectors to be added , change it at your will

Comment: on is not an alias of live.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will only bind to existing elements unless you use a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

**Option #1**

Bind to the `click` event for the newly added elements in a callback (**after** the elements have been added to the DOM):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
}).done(function(){
    $('.rx').children().on('click', function() { 
        alert('got here');
    });
});
```

**Option #2**

Use a delegated event that you bind to the container:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rx > *', function() { 
    alert('got here');
});
```

*Note: You probably want to replace the asterisk in the selector with an actual element type or class that matches the children. Using asterisk in selectors should be avoided when possible. Another improvement of the above is to use a parent that is closer to `.rx` instead of binding directly to `document`*

Answer (score 3):

on() is not an alias of live(). It says "bind this future event to these children that I'm specifying of on element that I'm specifying that exists now"

```
$('.rx').on('click', '*', function(){alert('got here');});
```

but if it's the whole `<div class="rx...>` that's being created dynamically not the elements inside of it

```
$(document).on('click', '.rx > *', function(){alert('got here');});
```

Comment: `.live` has been deprecated in favor of `.on`, so it is the replacement. The difference lie in the syntax. Sorry for being nit-picky ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegated event. In a nutshell you need to specify a container element for jquery to "watch" for changes to the DOM, which means the on() function has a slightly different syntax:

```
$('body').children().on('click', '.rx',function(){alert('got here');});
```

This means it will watch the body (you should use a more specific element in reality), and find any element with the "rx" class. Now when the body has new elements dynamically inserted by javascript, they will be alerted as well.

Check the [jQuery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for full details.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for ALL the incredibly quick responses guys. Every time I tried to reply, there was another answer!!!.

I ended up using
 
`$('ol#posts').on('click', '.rx > *', function(){alert('here');});`

ol#posts was the nearest wrapping element (is the reason you use the nearest element to save jquery searching the WHOLE document?).

Much appreciated. That was shaping up to be a 'till dawn' head banger, like struggling with geolocation not working with apple-mobile-web-app-capable last night. Your discussions here helped me fix that one too.

Cheers.